# Валидация формы авторизации/регистрации в Django без обновления страницы

Tags: django, ajax

У меня есть шаблон авторизации, в котором левая часть отвечает за авторизацию, а правая за регистрацию
login.html

```
                    <!-- Регистрация -->
                    <div class="form-container sign-up-container">

                        <form class="form-control-login" action="{% url 'user:registration' %}" method="post" id="registration-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <h1>Регистрация</h1>
                            <div class="social-container">
                                <a href="#" class="social">
                                    <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g">
                                        <img src="{% static 'icons/vk.svg' %}" alt="vkontakte" width="38" height="38">
                                    </i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="social">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
                                        <img src="{% static 'icons/odnoclassniki.svg' %}" alt="odnoclassniki" width="38" height="38">
                                    </i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="social">
                                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in">
                                        <img src="{% static 'icons/google.svg' %}" alt="google" width="38" height="38">
                                    </i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <span>или используйте свой адрес электронной почты для регистрации</span>

                            <label for="id_email" class="form-label"></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-input" name="email"
                                         value="{% if form.email.value %}{{ form.email.value }}{% endif %}"
                                         id="id_email" placeholder="Телефон или почта" required>
                                         {% if form.email.errors %}
                                   <div style="color:red">{{ form.email.errors }}</div>
                                         {% endif %}

                            <label for="id_first_name" class="form-label"></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-input" name="first_name"
                                         value="{% if form.first_name.value %}{{ form.first_name.value }}{% endif %}"
                                         id="id_first_name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required>
                                         {% if form.first_name.errors %}
                                   <div style="color:red">{{ form.first_name.errors }}</div>
                                         {% endif %}

                            <label for="id_last_name" class="form-label"></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-input" name="last_name"
                                         value="{% if form.last_name.value %}{{ form.last_name.value }}{% endif %}"
                                         id="id_last_name" placeholder="Введите вашу фамилию" required>
                                   {% if form.last_name.errors %}
                                   <div style="color:red">{{ form.last_name.errors }}</div>
                                         {% endif %}

                            <label for="id_username" class="form-label"></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-input" name="username"
                                         value="{% if form.username.value %}{{ form.username.value }}{% endif %}"
                                         id="id_username" placeholder="Введите ваш username" required>
                                         {% if form.username.errors %}
                                   <div style="color:red">{{ form.username.errors }}</div>
                                         {% endif %}

                            <label for="id_password1" class="form-label"></label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-input" name="password1"
                                         value="{% if form.password1.value %}{{ form.password1.value }}{% endif %}"
                                         id="id_password1" placeholder="Введите ваш пароль" required>
                                         {% if form.password1.errors %}
                                   <div style="color:red">{{ form.password1.errors }}</div>
                                         {% endif %}

                            <label for="id_password2" class="form-label"></label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-input" name="password2"
                                         value="{% if form.password2.value %}{{ form.password2.value }}{% endif %}"
                                         id="id_password2" placeholder="Подтвердите пароль" required>
                                         {% if form.password2.errors %}
                                   <div style="color:red">{{ form.password2.errors }}</div>
                                         {% endif %}

                            <button type="submit">Регистрация</button>
                        </form>

                        <script>
                            $(document).on('submit', '#registration-form', function (e) {
                              e.preventDefault();


                              $.ajax({
                                url: '/user/login/',
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {
                                  email: $('#id_email').val(),
                                        first_name: $('#id_first_name').val(),
                                        last_name: $('#id_last_name').val(),
                                        username: $('#id_username').val(),
                                        password1: $('#id_password1').val(),
                                        password2: $('#id_password2').val(),
                                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                                },
                                success: function (data){
                                  $('#success').html(data)
                                },
                              })
                            })
                        </script>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Авторизация -->
                    <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
                    <form class="form-control-login" action="{% url 'user:login' %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% if request.GET.next %}
                          <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                        <h1>Вход</h1>
                        <div class="social-container">
                        <a href="#" class="social">
                            <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g">
                                <img src="{% static 'icons/vk.svg' %}" alt="vkontakte" width="38" height="38">
                            </i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="social">
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
                                <img src="{% static 'icons/odnoclassniki.svg' %}" alt="odnoclassniki" width="38" height="38">
                            </i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="social">
                            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in">
                                <img src="{% static 'icons/google.svg' %}" alt="google" width="38" height="38">
                            </i>
                        </a>
                        </div>

                        <label for="id_email" class="form-label"></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-input" name="username"
                                     id="id_email" placeholder="Телефон или почта" required>

                        <label for="id_password" class="form-label"></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-input" name="password"
                                     id="id_password" placeholder="Пароль" required>

                        <a href="#">Забыли пароль?</a>
                        <button type="submit">Вход</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="overlay-container">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                                <h1>Добро пожаловать!</h1>
                                <p>Пожалуйста, войдите, используя свои личные данные.</p>
                                <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Вход</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                                <h1>Привет, Друг!</h1>
                                <p>Введите свои личные данные и начните арендовать вместе с нами</p>
                                <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Регистрация</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="pop-up-close" id="pop-up-close">&#10006</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Перемещение между формами происходит с помощью javascript[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все находится на маршруте user/login

```
from django.urls import path

from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('registration/', views.registration, name='registration'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
]

При неверном вводе данных при регистрации, страница обновляется и пользователю придется опять сдвигать шаблон на регистрацию, помогите настроить так чтобы не происходило обновления страницы

Вот views.py

    def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                auth.login(request, user)

                if request.POST.get('next', None):
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next'))

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index'))
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()

    context: dict = {
        'title': 'Lendme - Авторизация',
        'form': form
    }
    return render(
        request,
        template_name='users/login.html',
        context=context
    )


    def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = form.instance
            auth.login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index'))

    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    context: dict = {
        'title': 'Lendme - Регистрация',
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(
        request,
        template_name='users/login.html',
        context=context
    )
```